# Entire functions with only real zeros

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am considering the following problem:
$f_n$ is a sequence of entire functions and $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.Suppose each $f_n$ has only real zeros, then by Rouche's theorem, $f$ also has only real zeros.

Now my question is:Can we say $f$ must have real zeros? I have no idea about it, can anyone help me?

Comment: A simple counterexample is $f_n(z) = e^{z-1/n}$ which converges to $f(z) = e^z$ and $f$ has no zeros at all.

Comment: @MartinR I'm not sure that's a counterexample. The conditions and conclusion of the statement are vacuously satisfied.

Comment: A slightly more interesting (counter)example is $f_n(z) = (1-z/n)e^z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the limit function need not have zeros at all. A simple example is
$$
 f_n(z) = \left(1 - \frac zn\right) e^z
$$
which converges locally uniformly to $f(z) = e^z$. Slightly more general,
$$
 f_n(z) = g\left(\frac zn\right) e^{h(z)}
$$
where both $g$ and $h$ are entire functions, $g$ has only real zeros, and $g(0) \ne 0$.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet: Yes, that conclusion holds only if $f$ is not identically zero.

Comment: I deleted my comment accidentally. It was that $f$ can have non-real zeroes, e.g. $f_n(z)=n^{-1}\sin z.$